# Cloud Build doesn't fetch repository with Github App

Tags: git, github, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, google-cloud-build

I've configured Github App for push trigger in the Cloud Build.

And sometimes I get the following result:

```
starting build "16bb1123-b7e4-4ad6-9352-23fca851ab01"

FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
...
```

The expected behaviour for FETCHSOURCE step is usually pulling the code:
starting build "3272e8da-2c0a-466c-825e-4068e9ff3d98"

```
FETCHSOURCE
Initialized empty Git repository in /workspace/.git/
From https://github.com/***/***
 * branch            *** -> FETCH_HEAD
HEAD is now at ***
BUILD
```

The problem is it happens rarely and randomly one of 10-15 builds are failing with that.
Is there a bug in Google Issue Tracker or maybe someone had the similar problem?

Comment: Hi @NikitaZavyalow this seems to be more of a specific issue of configuration/environment, that would need to be checked. I would recommend you to reach out to [Google 1:1 Support](https://cloud.google.com/support), so they can access your instance configuration and investigate further the issue.

Comment: Thank you @gso_gabriel, there is also a connected issue in their tracker -> https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/136435027